# Nested callbacks in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a small problem with nested callbacks in javascript. Apparently im doing something wrong, but i did my research and tried to follow the tutorials avaialble throughout the web. I know that my code works, since query returns proper data, but i have no idea why my code doesnt "wait" within `executeQuery` method till the `res` is fetched from database, it just goes straight to "oh noes" section.

```
DatabaseConnection.prototype.executeQuery = function(query, executeQueryDone){
var activeConnection;
console.log("YEAAA, executing Query: " + query);

    this.pool.getConnection(function (err, connection){
        console.log("Got Connection, we are ready to go!");
        if (err){
            console.log("Error, DAMMNIT! " + err);
            executeQueryDone(err);
        }

        activeConnection = connection;
        activeConnection.connect();
        activeConnection.query(query, function(error, res){
            console.log("Connection from pool is executing Query");
            if(error){
                console.log("Error during executing query");
                executeQueryDone(error);
            }
            else {
                console.log(" OK now release connection (dont be selfish)! ");
                activeConnection.release();
                executeQueryDone(null, res);
            }
        });
    });
    console.log("oh noes! IM AFTER CONNECTION, why dude? WHY???? ");
};
```

I'd be grateful for any hints since im struggling with that since yesterday.

=====================

## PROBLEM SOLVED:

generally all was OK, the "issue" was mistakenly written test:

i made it like that:

```
describe('testDB2', function () {
 it('should return proper STUFF', function (done) {
   assert.equal(1, someService.getStuff(function(err, result){
    if (err === null){
        console.log("err is null, as it should be!");
    }
    console.log(" result from DB " + result[1].NUMBERS);
  })); 
 });
});
```

while is should be like that:

```
describe('testDB2', function () {
 it('should return proper STUFF', function (done) {
    someService.getStuff(function(err, result){
     assert.equal(err, null);
     assert.equal(result[1].NUMBERS, 43637654);
     done();
   });  
 });
});
```

as a result (in the incorrect case), i didnt fetch the result the way i wanted as assert couldnt "catch up"

thanks to all for the enlightment ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your console.log call isn't part of a callback, so it will be called as soon as the getConnection call is made. If you want it to be called only after your callback to getConnection fires, you either need to call it at the end of that call, or you need to use some form of [promises](https://api.jquery.com/promise/).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is single threaded, but it does use a task queue. When the database connection is instantiated and the pool connected to, the response to that is placed into the task queue to be executed or actioned when complete.

Directly after placing that in the task queue the next piece of execution is the log that does the "oh noes" - nice messaging btw lol.

So essentially what happens is the db call gets placed in the task queue for later execution, and then the log occurs, and then the task queue executes at a later time with the db response.